# Failed to download repository information

Tags: apt, 19.04, software-sources

I'm getting these errors:

```
W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_AU) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3, 
W:Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3, 
W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3, 
W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3,
E:The repository 'http://deb.playonlinux.com disco Release' does not have a Release file.,
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tsbarnes/indicator-keylock/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: thanks. I literally know nothing about this stuff.

Comment: Update: that python thing didn't fix it.

Comment: What errors are you getting now? You had two problems. Please follow David's script for remove `W:Target...` and remove repository which don't have release file for your distribution from *Other Software* tab in *Software and Updates* app. If issue still persists, please [edit] your question and add more details. If you want to ping me, use @Kulfy in comments. Thanks :)